# How do you convert XAML 3d object postitions, normals texture coordinates into C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, model, 3d

So I have a 3d object that I created and imported into XAML format and into Viewport3d. We have another C# object that is used from a book. The issue is that it is a parent object and trying to put the code behind file under the new object in C# creates a parent vs. parent conflict. I decided to make a c# class out of it as I need multiple instances of the object. I've been translating all the XAML code to C# but I'm stuck at the positions, normals, & texture coordinates of the XAML object. If there was an easier workaround instead of translating it, it would make my day. Can anyone help please? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can have multiple instances of XAML objects as well

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert it you can parse the XAML to an object using the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class which provides parsing methods.